# URL Rewriting on index page

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a website ***https://www.example.com**. I want to open home, category, and sub-category dynamically like:

```
https://www.example.com
https://www.example.com/education
https://www.example.com/education/PHP-Training
```

I have codded index.php like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['category'])){
        $category = $_GET['category'];
        $subCategory = $_GET['subcategory'];
        include('files/categoryFile.php');
    }else{ 
        include('files/indexFile.php');
    }
```

`categoryFile.php` will use the above two variables `$category`, `$subCategory` to get the data from the database and `indexFile.php` is static file for index page.
Below is the code of `.htaccess` for the rewrite rule to do the same:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+) index.php?category=$1&subcategory=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?category=$1 [NC,L]
```

It works alright here but the problem is, it also rewrite `https://www.example.com/css/style.css` to the same rule. I can stop it from rewriting these particular folders by using dropping `.htaccess` file to this folder with below code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

#Disable rewriting
RewriteEngine Off

</IfModule>
```

But it doesn't look like a good solution to me. I want to know if there is a better solution for this. If this question doesn't match the question criteria. Please comment it and I will delete the question. Also, suggest an edit if there could be a change. Thanks

Comment: use a rewrite condition to ignore specific files or filetypes

Comment: I have tried it but it hadn't worked. It just ignores the file type rule. @Bernhard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this thing in one of my project. You have to add one condition to before your rewrite rule and one more thing that is you should create assets folder so you can store there all public files and folders and you can make public using one rule.

Check this solution according your example.

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/css
    RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+) index.php?category=$1&subcategory=$2 [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?category=$1 [NC,L]
```

I think you just need to add a couple more conditions to exclude them.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/css
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/js
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/images
```

Comment: how will I add more folders to not rewrite list `%{REQUEST_URI} !/css, /images, /js, /folder` or `%{REQUEST_URI} !/(images|css|js|folder)$ [NC]`. I am sorry. I am new to .htaccess

Comment: You can add like this

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/clients/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/somefolder/

Comment: different line for different folder?

Comment: Yes you are Right . Check my above answer i have updated for that.

Comment: Doesn't look any problem until now. Thanks a lot @BhavinThummar

Comment: @PrashantRajpoot If it is solved then you can tick as right answer.

Comment: It was not solved. It was temporary and I have to do it like before

Comment: @PrashantRajpoot What is the issue now ?

Comment: It just ignore this rule

Comment: @PrashantRajpoot Can you show your full htaccess file code?